# UNIX script - print line of array based on contents of location (regex)

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I am using KornShell Scripting and I am splitting a file into an array

```
set -A fileArray $(< ${BTEQLOG} )
```

The array contains elements like this:

{RUN_ID, OPERATOR_ID, CYCLE_DES, PROJECTION_PROJECT_NME, ROW_CREATE_TSP, STATUS_DES, 195777, req82565, NII, 2016, -, ... }

I need to use the element(s) that match the pattern of {6}[0-9], like 195777 above.  I thought about checking to see if it is a number as below,

```
for l in ${fileArray[@]}
do
  echo $l
  if [[ $l -gt 10000 ]]; then
    echo $l
  fi
done
```

but all I got back was a `RUN_ID: bad number` error.

Is there a way to use regular expression to get what I want? The way I have it above may work, but I would prefer a regex to use just that instance.

I did try this:

```
typeset -i line=$l  
    if [[ $line = {6}[0-9] ]]; then
        echo $line;
    fi
```

but ran into the same `bad number` error from above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this works with ksh, but it does with bash.

```
if [[ "$line" =~ '^[0-9]{6}$' ]]; then
  echo "$line";
fi
```